# How to add an array of text inputs in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an array which I'm using to display a checkbox list bounded to a model.

When an item is checked the model populate an array. I'm using this array in another **v-for** which I display checked items. So far so good. Now I want to display a text input next to each checked item.

Now the problem is I'm not sure how to bind these new text inputs to a model.

I tried something like below. But it doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
<ul v-for="player in players">
    <li>
        <label :for="player.id">
            <input type="checkbox" :id="player.id" :value="player" v-model="checkedNames"> {{player.name}}
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul v-for="checked in checkedNames">
    <li>{{checked.name}} <input type="number" v-model="scores[checked.id]"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: In your loop you can set v-model to item that is iterated from array.For example when you iterate over `players` and each player has `skill` proprerty, you can asign v-model, into the loop, like this `<input type="text" v-model="player.skill">` and it would work.

Comment: @BelminBedak what I want is to create a new list with checked players. And in the new list I want to add a score text input to only checked players.

Comment: Js fiddle with thing you so far done would be helpful.

Comment: @BelminBedak something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/o999m5km/

Comment: something like this https://jsfiddle.net/3f1h5dfh/1/ ?

Comment: @BelminBedak :) this makes sense and looks like it solves my problem. Thanks. But isn't there a way to add an array of dynamic input elements?

Comment: Could you please clarify a bit, what should mean " add an array of dynamic input elements" ?